# Laravel Nova - Only load relationship with certain property in form dropdown

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have added a BelongsTo relationship field(relationship name: user) in my Nova app in resource named "Partner". So in the "create partner" form now I have a select element to choose a specific user.

The relationship I have written includes a condition:

```
$this->belongsTo('App\User')->where('role', 'partner');
```

In the select dropdown, instead of only showing users with role "partner", all users of the app are listing. How can I fix this issue?

```
User table : id, name, role
Partner table : id, user_id, name
```

Partner Model:

```
class Partner extends Model
{

  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'user_id'
  ];

  public function User()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->where('role', 'partner');
  }

}
```

Nova Resource fields method for Partner:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        Text::make('Name')->sortable(),
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        BelongsTo::make('User', 'user', 'App\Nova\User')->rules('required'),
        HasMany::make('Clients'),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add the relatableQuery for `User` under `Partner` Nova resource. No need the where condition in `Partner` model.

```
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;
...

public static function relatableUsers(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->where('role', 'partner');
}
```

Comment: What if I need to avoid already chosen user from listing? That looks tricky to implement.

Comment: Need to modify the query depends on your need. Avoid already chosen user means, the user belongs to another partner?

Comment: I figured it out. I just updated it to
`$query->where('role', 'partner')->doesntHave('partner');`

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam, your suggestion solve my problem. I wonder how do you know there is a "relatableQuery" function? It seems undocumented in laravel nova documentation. Thank you.

Comment: @Imran Learned about `relatableQuery` from https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/authorization.html#relatable-filtering

Comment: Thank you @SauminiNavaratnam. Have a nice day.