# Laravel Nova User field with role

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova, laravel-permission

I am fairly new to Nova, but have used php for years etc.

In an application I am building I have a relationship table set up which has the following fields in the Nova Resource file:

```
ID::make()->sortable(),
BelongsTo::make('Property'),
BelongsTo::make('User'),
Boolean::make("Active")
```

I am using Spatie role plugin, and would like to be able use a BelongsTo:make where the role equals "Cleaner".

Is there a way that I could do this?
If any more details are needed then please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331599/laravel-nova-only-load-relationship-with-certain-property-in-form-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

In your resource you can override the indexQuery.

Add the following

```
/**
 * Build an "index" query for the given resource.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->role('Cleaner')->get();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply ;)